# Access local resource in windows and mac desktop apps with .net MAUI

Tags: .net, .net-maui, maui-blazor, maui-windows

Is there a way I can access the local hard drive (all folders) while writing a desktop app for windows and mac using .net MAUI.
Tried looking at the docs site and nothing as such available there.

This also includes calling a CLI app running in windows or mac desktop system.

Comment: `.NET MAUI` is a cross-platform framework for creating native mobile and desktop apps with C# and XAML. If you want to access the app's cache and data directories and help access files in the app package, you can use [File system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=ios). Otherwise, if you need platform function, you can google it with key words.